# Magento: What is the url for creating a new order for a customer and store in the admin area?

Tags: magento

I've created a button within the Admin theme, which is named 'Create order for Johnsons'

Basically on this button I want to point it to the new create order screen for customerid 3 and store 2. Something like this:

```
$key=Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey("sales_order_create","index"); 
echo $COUrl=Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/new/",array("customer_id"=>"3","key"=>$key));
```

Please can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the key, `getUrl` does that for you when in an admin context.

```
echo $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_create/start', array('customer_id' => 3));
```

When using `start` like this it wipes all parameters except `customer_id` so a store cannot be specified. It will respect a `store_id` parameter if you change the URL to `*/sales_order_create/index` but that does not start a new order so it would be problematic. To get that to work you will have to create a new controller and action for your own use and make it almost exactly like [`Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController::startAction()`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6-trunk/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php):

```
/**
 * Start order create action
 */
public function startAction()
{
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->clear();
    $this->_redirect('*/sales_order_create', array(
        'customer_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id'),
        'store_id'    => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id')
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hey, Seriously - Big thanks. This looks like it could be very useful. I'll be trying this out first thing in the morning. I'm not 100% about how to create a controller etc. But it will give me something to research. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Controllers are [comprehensively documented](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch).

Comment: Anybody has an idea how to make the same URL, but so that it directs to New Order form with a New Customer?
I tried `$this->getUrl('*/sales_order_create/start', array('customer_id' => 0)`  , also `('customer_id' => false)`, but it anyway opens the grid with Customers, i.e. same page which is opened when standard "Create New Order" is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new customer instead of choosing one upon creating a new order you have to set customer_id as false this way:

```
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/session_quote')->setData('customer_id',false);
```

Why? Because using

```
$this->getUrl('*/sales_order_create/any_action_controller', array(
        'customer_id' => false
    ));
```

won't help for the reason of implementation in Sales/Order/CreateController

```
if ($customerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id')) {
        $this->_getSession()->setCustomerId((int) $customerId);
    }
```

As you can see there's "int" there that will convert anything you send through and we need false to be set as customer_id since otherwise Magento will create grids first.